# Center font awesome icon in a container div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button with two texts and one font-awesome icon. The two texts should be left-aligned, while the icon should be center-aligned.

[image]

```
<div className="overlay">
    <span>Unifyed</span><br/>
    <span style={{fontSize: "14px", textAlign: "left"}}>iOS Developer</span><br/>
    <span><i className="icon fa fa-plus" /></span>
</div>

.overlay {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Since the text and the icon are both contained in `overlay`, is there any way to assign them to different styles? I've tried to divide the text and the icon into two different `overlay` classes, but since it's an overlay, I need all three of these to be under one parent container.

Comment: are you trying to have each line of text or icon have their own style? If so, you can just assign an id to each and modify their css

Comment: I can't apply the styling to each `span` or `i`. I need to apply it to the parent container. If I want to center align the icon, I can't just apply it to the icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<i>` tags are *not* self closing.... `<i class="xxxxx"></i>` and they, along with spans, are always displayed as inline... change it to inline-block or block.

And avoiding the use of `<br />` tags would serve you well if you *ever* need to update the markup. `<br />` tags are **evil**.

```css
.overlay {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

/* below is added because clearly your CSS here is incomplete */

.overlay { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <span>Unifyed</span>
    <span style="fontSize: 14px;">iOS Developer</span>
    <span style="text-align: center;"><i class="icon fa fa-plus"></i></span>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Comment: He shouldn't be using the `<span>` tag in the first place. There's some place for semantic HTML there.

Comment: Agreed. more a case for paragraphs than spans.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation :) I'll keep these suggestions in mind as well.

Answer (score 2):

Simply only add the icon into other div inside overlay div and aply text-align:center;

```css
.overlay {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
    padding:15px;
}

.overlay .icon{
  text-align:center;
  padding:8px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="overlay">
    <span>Unifyed</span><br/>
    <span style={{fontSize: "14px", textAlign: "left"}}>iOS Developer</span><br/>
    <div class="icon">
      <span><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    
</div>
```